# Хранение токена авторизации для restApi

Tags: авторизация, rest

Приложение делает запрос к серверу авторизации с помощью *public key* и *private key*, получает при прохождении авторизации токен. Так вот, когда мы получаем этот токен, мы его получаем на какой-либо *callback*, и как нужно его правильно сохранить у себя в приложении? Записать в базе приложения в виде: *пользователь - токен* и при каждом запросе брать из базы запись токена и отправлять в заголовке? Сейчас по крайней мере так планирую сделать, или может есть какие то более правильные варианты или я вообще неправильно понял суть авторизации в *restApi*?

Comment: получили токен и держите его в памяти. если он вам нужен на случай перезагрузки серевера (бывает такое в облачных системах), то запишите этот токен куда-то. в файл или базу и т.д.